# Overload operator "+" in c++ depending from the parameters

Tags: c++, class, overloading, reload, operator-keyword

### Let us consider

we have created our own class Array. And now we want to overload "+" operator so that if:

```
Array a(5), b(3);
Array c = a + b;
```

it simply glues together a array and b array and we get a c array with length 5+3=8.

Now, I have realised this case writing in me Array.cpp file:

```
Array Array::operator+(const Array &Right)
{
Array temp_A(m_iCurInd+Right.m_iCurInd);
// here some stuff, not important to the quastion// 
return temp_A;
}
```

And everything is fine.

### But what if I want to :

```
Array a(5);
Array c = a + 2;
Array d = 2 + a;
```

So that d and c had lengths 6, with "2" in the beginning and in the end respectively?

### I have tried

to realise the firs case, so in Array.h file it was such a line:

```
Array operator+(const int &value); //a+2
```

And in Array.cpp:

```
Array Array::operator+(const int &value)
{
 Array temp_A(m_iCurInd+1);
 // here some stuff, not important to the quastion//
 return temp_A;
}
```

But it doesn't compiles, because it doesn't likes the types (particulary const int & I think). How shell I make it? Shell it be:

```
Array int::operator+(const Array &Right){
....
}
```

for the "2+a" case or something simmilar? Please advise me.

Comment: Implement the operator as a freestanding function: `Array Array::operator+(const Array &Left, const Array &Right)` plus two more operators for elements

Comment: @DieterLücking, shell it be in Array.cpp but outside the class{}?

Comment: This looks very confusing. Please don't do this.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit , what do you mean?

Comment: @greyxray: It looks like an abuse of operator overloading. A user of your code will not be able to tell just by reading it what `+2` does. `+` is not a conventional operator here. Better to write `prepend(int)` and `append(int)` member functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might do this:

```
class Array
{
    // ...

    // Insert an Element
    public:
    void prepend(int);
    void append(int);

    // Append an Array
    void append(const Array&);

    // ...
};

inline Array operator + (const Array& a, const Array& b) {
    Array result(a);
    result.append(b);
    return result;
}

inline Array operator + (const Array& a, int b) {
    Array result(a);
    result.append(b);
    return result;
}

inline Array operator + (int a, const Array& b) {
    Array result(b);
    result.prepend(a);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would define operator+ as a non-member function to support mixed-mode arithmetic.

```
Array operator+( const Array &arr1, const Array &arr2 )
```

and then provide appropriate single argument constructor for the types you want to support mixed-mode arithmetic.

Comment: I'm just a beginner. Could you please explain where I should place(in maint? in other file/class?)?

Comment: You can declare it inline in the header( where you have defined your class) outside the class definition.

Comment: thank you, I will try it. But shell I also rewrite the part I've done this way or it can stay?

Answer (score 0):

To allow the syntax `Array + int` you have two options: Create a member function overload of `operator+` where the parameter it takes is an integer, or create a free `operator+` whose parameters are `Array` and `int` respectively. It looks like you've done it correctly for the member function overload, but to make sure, it should look like this:

```
class Array
{
    // ...
    Array operator+(int rhs)
    {
        // ...
    }
};
```

Now `Array + int` should work. If it doesn't, you've done something wrong inside the function.

To allow the syntax `int + Array` you need a free operator function because the member function won't overload `int` for the left side:

```
Array operator+(int lhs, Array const& rhs)
{
    return rhs + lhs;
}
```

`rhs + lhs` calls the member function overload `Array::operator+()`.